# Intentional placing of text in clipboard

Tags: javascript, website-features, flash

By intentional I mean the user is actively clicking a button or performing an action that leads to certain text being places in their clipboard. As far as I know the only solution to this is [Zero Clipboard](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/), but I feel like it's not accepted as a good solution since it uses flash. Are there any alternatives if I want to allow users to copy specific text information at the click of a button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the answer is no.
Javascript has the methods to copy to clipboard, however browsers don't allow them for security purposes...

I'm afraid i've to say that flash is the only solution.

Comment: Look carefully - the methods talked about in the MDC article you linked to are meant for *add-on* authors, whose scripts have higher privileges than any scripts that run on websites

Comment: Indeed. I'm sorry for that one! I guess i shouldn't have read it "diagonally"